# How to optimize the reading of a file removing all the line feed \n characters

Tags: python, performance

I need to read from a file several integers written line by line and separated by line feed and insert them into a list.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Currently I was able to read it using the following code, but I need also to optimize my code:

```
import sys

fd = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for line in fd:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    L.append(int(line))
```

Is there another way to read from a file all the lines removing the line feed characters from a performance point of view ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()` automatically removes the white-space characters,so there's no need of `str.rstrip`.

```
>>> int('10\r\n')
10
>>> int('10\n')
10
>>> int('10  \n')
10
```

You can also use a list comprehension here, it is faster than `list.append`:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fd:
    L = [int(line) for line in fd]
```

[Why the `with` statement?](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

Comment: Did we both just post at the exact same time?

Comment: @Haidro No, actually I beat you to it by 2 seconds. :P

Comment: Ah, guess my page didn't say that an answer had been added :p

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need to strip the line because `int()` already gets rid of trailing whitespace:

```
L = []
with open('nums.txt') as myfile: # With statements are more pythonic!
    for line in myfile:
        L.append(int(line))

print L
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

As a result, you can then use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
with open('nums.txt') as myfile:
    L = map(int, myfile)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Using a list comprehension will be quicker as the loop and the append will not be done in python, but by the runtime engine. (Also you do not need to strip the newlines).

```
[int(line) for line in fd]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/), specifically [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), e.g:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt("yourfile.dat",delimiter="\n")
```

This will make `data` a numpy array with as many rows and columns as are in your file